Reuse React component for different purposes
I have a React project that make use of a component that I want to use in two situations:

The component is used to display data in an interactive mode. In this mode, UI elements can be (double) clicked to update the state of the app, which is stored in a context
The component is used in a read only mode. In this case, the UI elements are not interactive (or in some cases, another function needs to be called)

Of course, I can provide the component with the on(double)click functions as props. This is what I am currently doing. However, the functions are not used by the component itself but, instead, by components within. For this approach to work, I therefore have to use prop drilling and pass the functions down to where they are used.
I want to prevent this prop drilling, ideally by getting the functions from the context. So, my question is: what other options do I have. What would be a good pattern to use here.
To clarify here is a highly simplified representation of my setup:
App.tsx:
const App = () => {
  return (
    <MyContextProvider>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={<MainComponent />} />
        <Route
          path="/other"
          element={<OtherComponent />} />
      </Routes>
    </MyContextProvider>
  );
}

MyContextProvider
Contains the state of my application, which is used by both MainComponent and OtherComponent
MainComponent
const MainComponent = () => {
  return <ReusableComponent
    methodA={method1}
    methodB={method2} />
}

OtherComponent
(note, different methods are being passed to ReusableComponent than MainComponent)
const OtherComponent = () => {
  return <ReusableComponent
    methodA={method3}
    methodB={method4} />
}

ReusableComponent
const ReusableComponent = ({ methodA, methodB}) => {
    return (
      <ComponentThatNeedsMethods 
        methodA={methodA}
        methodB={methodB} />
    );
}

Note that ReusableComponent is doing nothing with methodA and methodB, but it just passes it on to ComponentThatNeedsMethods. In real life, ComponentThatNeedsMethods is also not using the methods but, instead, a component deeply nested in ComponentThatNeedsMethods is using it.

Why do you want to prevent this?

"what other options do I have" typically composition, possibly through render props. IIRC, should be mentioned in React docs about context and props drilling. If you can share some code and specifics of the interactions with your child components, it should be much easier to see pros and cons.

https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context#before-you-use-context "Extract components and pass JSX as children to them. If you pass some data through many layers of intermediate components that don’t use that data (and only pass it further down), this often means that you forgot to extract some components along the way."

I have added a simplified example to the description
